# Jasmine unit testing, how do I trigger the click event of ngx-modal-dialog

Tags: javascript, angular, unit-testing, jasmine, jasmine-jquery

I am working on an angular application and i am Unit testing the application using Jasmine.

The application uses `ngx-modal-dialog`([enter link description here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-modal-dialog)) plugin for Pop-up Dialog Box such as a a confirmation box as a dynamic component.

[image]

What i want is to trigger the click event for the confirm or cancel, whatever the user chooses.

The code for the Pop-up Dialog box is as below:

```
export class SomeComponent {

constructor(private modalService: ModalDialogService) {}
cancleEditConfirmDialog() {
   this.modalService.openDialog(this.viewRef, {
   title: 'Discard Changes ',
   childComponent: SimpleModalComponent,
   data: {
     text: 'Changes will not be saved. Do you want to proceed?'
   },
   settings: {
     closeButtonClass: 'close theme-icon-close'
   },
   actionButtons: [
     {
       text: 'Discard',
       buttonClass: 'btn btn-success',
       onAction: () => new Promise((resolve: any) => {
         // invoke delete
         // do something such as discard changes
         resolve()
       })
     },
     {
       text: 'Cancel',
       buttonClass: 'btn btn-danger',
       onAction: () => new Promise((resolve: any) => {
         // cancel and close popup
         setTimeout(() => {
           resolve();
         }, 20);
       })
     }
   ]
 });
}
}
```

> how do i trigger the `onAction: => ()` in the click event for discard button
>   and for cancel button.

[image]
[image]

Comment: If you setup your TestBed with the original ngx-modal-dialog you can just open the modal using the debugElem.triggerEventHandler(‚click‘) on the element opening the dialog and than you could just access the cancel and discard buttons again as a debugElem and use the triggerEventHandler. If the ngx-modal-dialog has too many dependencies you don‘t want to add to your test because you would like to shallow test your component you could mock the ngx-modal-dialog

Comment: @Erbsenkoenig thanks for the reply. I tried it,but its a bootstrap component so it still shows as `cannot find nativeElement of null`.

Comment: can you tell me how can mock it

Comment: I'll try to make a stackblitz.

Comment: Could you do me a favour and edit this stackblitz (https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-xawnbl) so the dialog is working. I haven't worked with this particular modal dialog before. Afterwards I'll do the testing bit.

Comment: I have got it working. Now you can continue with it. The problem was probably with `click` -> `(click)`

Comment: Oh yeah that's right^^. I'll have a look at the test.

Comment: Posted the test setup etc as an answer. To test the dialog I used the approach to actually use the ngx-modal-dialog. There would be the way of mocking it too, if you would prefer that approach please let me know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a problem, with testing this modal dialog, if the viewRef passed into the modalService is the actual component under test itself. This is because the modal dialog gets added into the dom outside the viewRef. So you could only access the elements inside the test using document.getElementById which would be possible, but you wouldn't have the chance to use all those nice debugElement features and so on.

There is a way though: if it's not a problem to use a div inside the component as the viewRef than the test could be done.

[stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ngx-modal-dialog-test)

This means your template would need to look like this:

**template**

```
<div #parentDialog>
  <button type="button" (click)="cancleEditConfirmDialog()">Open Dialog</button>
</div>
```

If thats the case the component would look like this:

**component.ts**

```
  @ViewChild('parentDialog', {read: ViewContainerRef}) parentVCR;

  constructor(private modalService: ModalDialogService) {}

  cancleEditConfirmDialog() {
   this.modalService.openDialog(this.parentVCR, {
   title: 'Discard Changes ',
   childComponent: SimpleModalComponent,
   data: {
     text: 'Changes will not be saved. Do you want to proceed?'
   },
   settings: {
     closeButtonClass: 'close theme-icon-close'
   },
   actionButtons: [
     {
       text: 'Discard',
       buttonClass: 'btn btn-success',
       onAction: () => new Promise((resolve: any) => {
         // invoke delete
         // do something such as discard changes
         resolve()
       })
     },
     {
       text: 'Cancel',
       buttonClass: 'btn btn-danger',
       onAction: () => new Promise((resolve: any) => {
         // cancel and close popup
         setTimeout(() => {
            resolve();
         }, 20);
       })
     }
   ]});
 }
```

And finally your test case:

**test**

```
describe('AppComponent', () => {
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<AppComponent>;
  let component: AppComponent;

  beforeEach(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [ModalDialogModule.forRoot()],
      declarations: [ AppComponent],
      schemas: [NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA]
    });

    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(AppComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;

    fixture.detectChanges();
  });

  it('open dialog and cancel', fakeAsync(() => {
     let buttonDebugElems: DebugElement[] = fixture.debugElement.queryAll(By.css('button'));
    expect(buttonDebugElems.length).toEqual(1);
    expect(buttonDebugElems[0].nativeElement.innerText).toEqual('Open Dialog');

    // Open
    buttonDebugElems[0].triggerEventHandler('click', null);
    fixture.detectChanges();

    buttonDebugElems = fixture.debugElement.queryAll(By.css('button'));
    expect(buttonDebugElems.length).toEqual(3);

    expect(buttonDebugElems[1].nativeElement.innerText).toEqual('Discard');
    expect(buttonDebugElems[2].nativeElement.innerText).toEqual('Cancel');

    // cancel
    buttonDebugElems[2].triggerEventHandler('click', null);
    // needed to wait for the promise to resolve (20 needed due to the timeout of the cancel promise)
    tick(20);

    buttonDebugElems = fixture.debugElement.queryAll(By.css('button'));
    expect(buttonDebugElems.length).toEqual(1);

     // todo expect the things the action changed inside you component.
  }));

  it('open dialog and discard', fakeAsync(() => {
    let buttonDebugElems: DebugElement[] = fixture.debugElement.queryAll(By.css('button'));
    expect(buttonDebugElems.length).toEqual(1);
    expect(buttonDebugElems[0].nativeElement.innerText).toEqual('Open Dialog');

    // open
    buttonDebugElems[0].triggerEventHandler('click', null);
    fixture.detectChanges();

    buttonDebugElems = fixture.debugElement.queryAll(By.css('button'));
    expect(buttonDebugElems.length).toEqual(3);

    expect(buttonDebugElems[1].nativeElement.innerText).toEqual('Discard');
    expect(buttonDebugElems[2].nativeElement.innerText).toEqual('Cancel');

    // discard
    buttonDebugElems[1].triggerEventHandler('click', null);
    // needed to wait for the promise to resolve
    tick();

    buttonDebugElems = fixture.debugElement.queryAll(By.css('button'));
    expect(buttonDebugElems.length).toEqual(1);

    // todo expect the things the action changed inside you component.

  }));
});
```

Comment: thank you so much for the effort and help. Though, it disturbed the UI of the component, I got it working the solution for testing part. Thanks alot.

Comment: Using the viewref from a div inside the component? You wouldn't need to wrap that div around the button, it could be a div anywhere inside your component if that helps with your UI. The only important thing is to not use the injected viewRef inside the constructor. You're welcome.

Comment: Its not helping yet.Tried to give `#parentDialog` on an existing `div` above button but Ui is still getting distorted :(.

Comment: Do you think you could recreate that in a stackblitz? Maybe fork this one here and share the url (that's the one I used to have a look at the dialog itself before doing the testing bit): https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-xawnbl

Comment: Another way could be to add it to a new div with a position absolute which is placed outside the view or has visibility: hidden or something like that. But this is just guessing into the blue without seeing the actual problem

Comment: Tried to produce it with stackblitz but, its a bit big component and the classes too are coming from bootstrap.css. Unable to produce the actual ui

Comment: And BTW the Ui that is getting distorted is for modal popup that is the modal popup's z-index is mixing up with background elements after the popup opens.

Comment: how can we switch to chats @Erbsenkoenig

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/189521/discussion-between-erbsenkoenig-and-saurabh-gupta).